# Problems displaying UTF8 Character with objective C

Tags: iphone, objective-c

in my app I have to get some data returned by a Server.. this data is in UTF8 encoding format.. So my server returns the following string:

> r\u00f3 do S\u00edt

in my code I do the following:

```
NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"%@",responseString);
```

the output is :

> r\u00f3 do S\u00edt

and it should be

> ró do sít

Am I doing something wrong?

let me show you guys,, how the all system is working..

I make a query on the mysql database.. all tables are UTF8 encoded..

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
//THE CONNECTION PART GOES HERE
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'UTF8'");
mysql_query('SET character_set_client=UTF8');       
mysql_query('SET character_set_results=UTF8');
mysql_query('SET character_set_connection=UTF8'); 

$query = "select * from table";
$out = mysql_query($query);
$rows = array();
while($reg = mysql_fetch_assoc($out)) 
{
    $rows[] = $reg;
}
print json_encode($rows);
```

then it prints the following on the browser:

> [{"class_id":"8","name":"r\u00f3
>   pir\u00e1","local_id":"10"},{"class_id":"9","name":"r\u00f3
>   do S\u00edtio","local_id":"8"}]

Comment: How is `responseData` assigned?

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure responseData is in UTF8 format?  Try hex dumping responseData and checking the bytes.

I should look something like:

0x72 0xc3 0xb3 0x20 0x64 0x6f 0x20 0x53 0xc3 0xad 0x74
'r'  'ó'       ' '  'd'  'o'  ' '  'S'  'í'       't'

I'm assuming 'ó' == 0x00f3 unicode point and 'í' == 0x00ed unicode point.

My guess is that the response data actually reads:

"r\u00f3 do S\u00edt"

in which case I would look at where responseData is generated, my guess would be that the conversation from a unicode string to a utfstring is incorrect or the source data is incorrect.  The '\uxxxx' looks like some sort of unicode point string encoding for some sort of language string literals maybe?

Comment: Shane.. thank you for your answer.. I guess that the responseData is in UTF8, because the all server side was configured to output UTF8.. take a look on the edited question.. I can be doing something wrong on the server.. I don't know.. 
thanks on advance!

Comment: Your updated question confirms my answer. Your string is encoded in JSON. Looking into JSON, it will encode unicode points (I assume outside of the ascii range) into the '\uXXXX' format.  http://www.json.org/fatfree.html  You need to decode the JSON string to get a correct unicode string either manually or with some library.

Answer (score 0):

try with

```
NSString *responseString = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@", [responseData bytes]];
```

Comment: The result was "EXC_BAD_ACCESS".. =/